# Any Phonegap automatic CSP (content security policy) injection workaround?

Tags: cordova, content-security-policy

Some of you might be aware that phonegap developer injects its own content security policy when testing on a phone.
You can check the full topic @ https://github.com/phonegap/connect-phonegap/issues/163

> timkim commented on 23 Sep 2016 Hi @additionbo 
>   **Like @chrisgriffith mentioned, connect-phonegap now modifies your CSP to ensure certain rules are set so communication between server and your device is possible. *The reason why you don't see the browser logging the CSP warning is that the CSP modifcation only happens when we zip up your project on the server side.***

So. Here's my problem, I can test my app in web browsers & on phones when accessing from the browser, everything works fine there, but once I open the phonegap developer app, my images are NOT loaded.

From my understanding, once I go ahead and compile an apk (in MS visual studio for example), there shouldn't be a problem (haven't tested compiling, as I only have this software on my workstation).

And it is not a good work around, as it really kills hurts my working environment and speed - if I was compiling every test, and uploading it to the phone, installing, ... etc. It takes a lot of time.

Is there a way I can force my own content security policy?
It currently looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * localhost 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com; media-src *; img-src IMAGE-SERVER.COM 'self'" />
```

And the CSP tag injected by Phonegap looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' gap: ws: https://ssl.gstatic.com;style-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'self' data: blob:;media-src *;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
```

Which from my understanding is what originates my problem. 
Very appreciated towards any suggestions.